# C Form DNA Base Pairs Per Turn

Tags: dna, molecular-genetics

How does C-DNA have 9.33 base pairs per turn? The number of base pairs should be quantised. How can it be a decimal?

Answer (score 5):

There is no requirement that DNA should have a whole number of base pairs per turn. As a thought experiment, say you have a helix of dsDNA with 10 base pairs that completes one helical turn (ie it has 10 bp/turn). Now, twist that DNA along its axis so that it completes 1.5 turns. There is still only 10 bp and thus 6.67 bp/turn (which you should notice is a decimal).